# RDC - Screen Shifts to Show Local Task Bar

Tags: windows-7, vpn, remote-desktop

I have scoured the internet trying to find an answer and hope someone can help.

I have a Windows 7 Pro laptop that I use to connect to a virtual machine at my place of work via a VPN.  I recently received a new laptop (previously it was Win7 Enterprise), and now when I RDC to my virtual machine running Win7 Enterprise N, I have the annoying issue of the screen "shifting" when I "push" against the top and bottom of the screen.  Essentially, when I move my mouse to the bottom of the task bar in the virtual machine, the whole RDC moves up and reveals the local/laptop taskbar.

The RDC is set to "Full Screen" on the Display RDC Options, and I've toggled the Connection Bar option.  Aero Peek was not on.

Any ideas?  It is terribly frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

If the 2 screens are the same resolution, or the remote is larger, the screen you remote to will actually need more space than you have, to show it inside the window, so it will auto-scroll.

Two ways to prevent auto-scroll are

- Set the resolution on the remote screen smaller than Native [which may mess with icon positions] or
- Use 'Scale content' in the RDC prefs for that screen.

Comment: I am using the "Use all my monitors for the remote session" option checked for my dual monitors and have the display configuration set to "Full Screen" for the rmeote sessions, so I am not sure why it would need more space that I have.  In the past, using both those options, the remote screen behaved like my desktop until I had the connection bar display by hovering at the top of the screen.  It feels like this would be an option somehow, but I cannot tell why it behaves this way.

Comment: I'm not sure how the 'all monitors' should work, as I have 2 screens, but all my remotes have only one. For me, fullscreen does work if the remote monitor is the same rez as my local, or smaller. If identical & I run the remote windowed, then I need to use 'scale' else the window surround messes me up. My solution has always been to just use scale rather than native. In short, I'm not sure I'm also suffering your issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (and also spent a good few hours searching for the answer), and it turns out that the way to fix it isn't in the RDC settings... you need to change them on your local computer's settings in the control panel. Here's a walk through:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Select Display
3. Select Screen Resolution
4. Select Advance
5. Select "On Screen Display" Tab
6. Uncheck "Enable Auto Scroll Function"
7. Press OK

I originally found the answer here:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Strange-display-scrolling-issue-when-using-extended-monitor-for/ta-p/556743